# child component not emitting output to parent component

Tags: angular

I have seen questions exactly similar to mine and even my application works in well in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rc1fxy) but in my local project which contains my components and modules and for the life of me and I can't figure why.

Background:

I decided to add Login with Google, which can happen from two sections of the project. Since there is some sort of logic applied behind with regards to the domain and others, I decided to create a separate child component with simple Open with Google Button.

I am getting the data from google successfully but can't emit back to the parent component. Getting rid of the google concept, I can't even emit normal values as you can see in the blitz.

What could be the reason for child component not to emit output to parent component? I am in Angular 7 that matters. My code is:

**google.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-google-login",
  template: `<button type="button" (click)="process()">
    Act
  </button>`
})
export class GoogleLoginComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() userDetails = new EventEmitter<any>(); 

  constructor() {}

  process(): void {
    /*
    emit data here
    */
    this.userDetails.emit('Done')
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**App.component.html**

```html
<app-google-login
  (userDetails)="emittedGoogleUserInformation($event)"
></app-google-login>
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
emittedGoogleUserInformation(info){
  console.log('google data from child component ', info);
}
```

Comment: No error in the console? Try clearing the browser cache and running the application again.

Comment: It works for me with an output in console as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
@Output() userDetails: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```